# Java Replace particular positioned delimiter with another delimeter

Tags: java, regex, string

Given this line:

```
String name="Summer,John,Alex,Stu,Mike,will,King,yahoo,Google,jeff";
```

I want to replace comma with `||` symbol after every 4th occurrence of the comma.

Expected output:

```
Summer,John,Alex,Stu||Mike,will,King,yahoo||Google,jeff
```

I have done this in `awk` command

```
awk -F, '{
     for (i=1; i<NF; i++) 
       printf "%s%s", $i, (i%4?FS:"||"); 
       print $i
}'
```

I am unable to convert this command into java regex.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can try this,

```
String name="Summer,John,Alex,Stu,Mike,will,King,yahoo,Google,jeff";
System.out.println(name.replaceAll("(\\w+,\\w+,\\w+,\\w+),", "$1||"));
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Summer,John,Alex,Stu||Mike,will,King,yahoo||Google,jeff
```

*Note :* `\\w+` means one or more word characters and  `$1` stands for group 1

**EDIT :**

> what if i want to replace 100th position? do i need to use 100 \w+?

Not really you can use grouping here again and specify `{}` count of occurrence of group something like,

```
String name="Summer,John,Alex,Stu,Mike,will,King,yahoo,Google,jeff,test,hell,";
System.out.println(name.replaceAll("((\\w+,){3}(\\w+)),", "$1||"));
```

Comment: what if i want to replace 100th position? do i need to use 100 \\w+?